# Save HTML Canvas drawing as jpg error

Tags: javascript, html, image, download, html5-canvas

trying to save a drawing using canvas, the file actually does download but I am hit with these errors when trying to open it 
PS: "Could not complete your request because a JPEG marker segment length is too short (the file may be truncated or incomplete)." 
Preview: "The file “my-file-name (5).jpg” could not be opened. It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize."

Any ideas? Here is the code:

```
JS:

var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
prevX = 0,
currX = 0,
prevY = 0,
currY = 0,
dot_flag = false;

var x = "black",
y = 2;

function init() {
canvas = document.getElementById('can');
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
w = canvas.width;
h = canvas.height;

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    findxy('move', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
    findxy('down', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
    findxy('up', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
    findxy('out', e)
}, false);
}

function color(obj) {
switch (obj.id) {
    case "green":
        x = "green";
        break;
    case "blue":
        x = "blue";
        break;
    case "red":
        x = "red";
        break;
    case "yellow":
        x = "yellow";
        break;
    case "orange":
        x = "orange";
        break;
    case "white":
        x = "white";
        break;
    case "black":
        x = "black";
        break;
}
if (x == "black") y = 14;
else y = 3;

}

function draw() {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
ctx.strokeStyle = x;
ctx.lineWidth = y;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
}

function erase() {
var m = confirm("Want to clear");
if (m) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
}
}

function save() {
document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
}

var button = document.getElementById('btn-download');
button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
button.href = dataURL;
});

function findxy(res, e) {
if (res == 'down') {
    prevX = currX;
    prevY = currY;
    currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

    flag = true;
    dot_flag = true;
    if (dot_flag) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = x;
        ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
        ctx.closePath();
        dot_flag = false;
    }
}
if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
    flag = false;
}
if (res == 'move') {
    if (flag) {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
        draw();
    }
}
}


HTML:

<a href="#" class="button" id="btn-download" download="my-file-name.jpg"   style="position:absolute;top:90%;left:23%;">Download</a>
<input type="button" value="save" id="btn" size="30" onclick="save()" style="position:absolute;top:90%;left:31%;">
<input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" onclick="erase()" style="position:absolute;top:90%;left:36%;">
```

Comment: @markE interesting when I right click and save as it opens the png fine with no issues, but something still isnt right with the download button fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

From the new information in the comment (the file itself) -

The image file uploaded turns out to be an HTML file, the source page itself. Now that I could, *coincidentally*, see the complete page it became obvious why things doesn't work.

The JavaScript is loaded in the head tag and tries to reference elements on the page which is not initialized yet (a page is always parsed linearly).

This causes the code to fail with `addEventListener` etc. as the call is invoked on an undefined element. This leads to the a-tag's href to not be updated as well, so it links t the page itself due to the hash-tag (`href="#"`). Since there is a download attribute defined in the html this doesn't become so evident, but results in the page itself being downloaded instead of the data-uri as the latter never gets assigned to the href attribute.

Hex dump:

[image: hex dump]

### Solution

The solution is simple however: By **moving the script to the end** (before the end body tag) it should work as intended (tested locally).

Alternatively: you wrap also wrap the script inside the following code block if you want to keep it in the header:

```
window.onload = function() {

    // script here

};
```

I would recommend the first approach though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much @Ken Fyrstenberg your answer made perfect sense, thanks for explaining in detail, unfortunately I'm having no success even when I change the image type back to the default of .png, I'm leaning toward it must be some other issue which is really frustrating - one question I has is if I declare the filename in the script do I still need to declare it in the download property of the button?

Comment: @gwar9 no need to declare it in html if you chose to set it in JavaScript. If possible, could you upload the image file you have problem with and share a link to it here? (not an image sharing service, but a file sharing one so we can see the original content).

Comment: here is a google drive link to the image thats viewable using right-click > save as [Google](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9FgRFYFweL0d1NDQWt4THFpdFk/view?usp=sharing).

Im just randomly scribbling on the canvas and trying to download the image.

Comment: Also @Ken Fyrstenberg I checked the console and this error is showing up "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null index.html:115"

Comment: Also here is a link to that file that can't be opened [Google](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9FgRFYFweL0cEpCWVlLbGMzOWc/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Frystenberg Brilliant, and such a rookie mistake on my part but now I know, thank you so much for your time and excellent solution!